# jquery panel and fixed list data filter

Tags: jquery, listview, panel

i would like a panel and fixed listview data filter

This result without panel it's ok : http://jsfiddle.net/AH6mC/1/

Bad result with panel : http://jsfiddle.net/VMhQ6/

```
 #MyWrapper {
    padding-top : 45px;
}
#MyWrapper form {
    position : fixed;
    top : 60px;
    left : 15px;
    width : 100%;
    z-index : 1;
}
```

Help me !!

Correction: Firefox its OK, Chrome problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This first solution :

Move data-filter :

```
$("#Acceuil").find("form.ui-listview-filter").appendTo("#Fixed")
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VMhQ6/1/